# 70 years old expatriate returning to the UK with expired pink paper GB driving licence

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm a British Expat who's just turned 70. I've been living and working in Malaysia for the past 5 years. During that time I had no UK address. I'll shortly be returning to the UK to a new permanent address. I wish to renew my GB driving licence and also change the address on said licence. The DVLA website online renewal service is no help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.gov.uk/renew-driving-licence-at-70? You need a UK address to apply, but it looks like it is possible to enter a previous, non-UK, address.